# Portable way of linking libgfortran with CMAKE

Tags: c++, cmake

One of my executables requires `libgfortran.so`. Typically I'd just add the `-lgfortran` switch to the compile line and it links automatically with `g++`. However, I'm trying to find the library with CMAKE using:

```
find_library(GFORTRAN_LIBRARY NAMES gfortran)
target_link_libraries(ncorr_test ${GFORTRAN_LIBRARY})
```

However, this fails to the find the library. It turns out the only way that has worked so far is if I include the entire library name like so:

```
find_library(GFORTRAN_LIBRARY NAMES libgfortran.so.3)
target_link_libraries(ncorr_test ${GFORTRAN_LIBRARY})
```

Then, it will link properly:

```
/usr/bin/c++ ... /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3 ...
```

However, including the whole `.so.3` is not very portable. Does anyone know of a better way to do this? Typically libraries I need to use are just installed in `/usr/local/lib` and searching for the library name without the "lib" and extension works (i.e. `find_library(FFTW_LIBRARY NAMES fftw3)` will find `libfftw3.a` in `/usr/local/lib` just fine).

**EDIT:**

`find_library(GFORTRAN_LIBRARY NAMES libgfortran.so)` does not work either. Only `libgfortran.so.3` has worked so far.

Using `locate libgfortran` outputs:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.a
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortran.spec
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/libgfortranbegin.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran-4.8-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgfortran3
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran-4.8-dev:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran-4.8-dev:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.shlibs
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libgfortran3:amd64.symbols
```

**EDIT2:**

For now I'll just require the user to copy `libgfortran.a` over to their `usr\local\lib` directory

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you either miss dev package on your linux distribution, which should install `.so` link, or path where such link located is missing when cmake does lookup. Try to find `libgfortran.so` link, usually it is located the same place where `.so.3` is, if you cannot find it install missing dev package, if you can check why that path is not included in cmake.

Comment: I've added more to the post in the edit. It appears CMAKE is only searching `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` which contains only `libgfortran.so.3`. It is not looking in `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/` which contains `libgfortran.a`, and `libgfortran.so`.

Comment: Have you found a way to get CMake to search /usr/lib/gcc/?